Who are these characters?
I ran across this image on Blender.SE, where it was used to illustrate that good cartoon characters have very recognizable silhouettes. What characters are in the image?


Here are the characters I have figured out. (Each row is listed from left to right.)
Top row:

Mickey Mouse
Daffy Duck
Fred Flintstone
Ren and Stimpy
Bart Simpson
Spongebob Squarepants
Felix the Cat
The Roadrunner

Second row:

Marge Simpson
Yogi Bear
Stewie Griffin
Popeye
Mr. Krabs
Charlie Brown
Bugs Bunny
Wilma Flintstone
Mighty Mouse

Third row:

Bullwinkle
Odie
Goofy
Squidward
Dexter
Snoopy
Mojo Jojo
Olive Oyl
Pink Panther

Last row:

Betty Boop
Arnold (Hey Arnold)
Casper the Friendly Ghost
Sherman and Peabody
Taz
Bobby (Bobby's World)
Pinky & The Brain
Marvin The Martian

